# Awk array, replace with full length matches of keys

Tags: awk

I want to replace strings in a target file (target.txt) by strings in a lookup table (lookup.tab), which looks as follows.

```
Seq_1 Name_one
Seq_2 Name_two
Seq_3 Name_three
...
Seq_10 Name_ten
Seq_11 Name_eleven
Seq_12 Name_twelve
```

The target.txt file is a large file with a tree structure (Nexus format). It is not arranged in columns.

Therefore I use the following command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { array[$1]=$2; next } { for (i in array) gsub(i, array[i]) }1'  "lookup.tab" "target.txt"
```

Unfortunately, this command does not take the full length of the elements from the first column, so that Seq_1, Seq_10, Seq_11, Seq_12 end up as Name_one, Name_one0, Name_one1, Name_one2 etc...

How can the awk command be made more specific to correctly substitute the strings?

Comment: please add example input

Comment: Your logic is broken anyway. What if one of the entries in lookup.tab is e.g. `Seq_1 Seq_2`?

Comment: They are sequentially labeled. Seq_1 and Seq_2 are there.

Comment: This feels more like a job for *sed* than *awk*.  If you converted each line in *lookup.tab* to its respective sed command (e.g., `s/Seq_1/Name_one/g`), you could do this with the command `sed -f lookup.tab < target.txt`.

Comment: Add your example input and expected output please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please, see if it meets your need:

```
awk 'FNR==NR { le=length($1); a[le][$1]=$2; if (maxL<le) maxL=le; next } { for(le=maxL;le>0;le--) if(length(a[le])) for (i in a[le]) gsub(i, a[le][i]) }1'  "lookup.tab" "target.txt"
```

It's based on your own trying, but instead of randomly replace using the hashes in the array, replace using those longer keys first.
By this way, and based on your examples, I think it's enough to avoid wrongly substitudes.